# Why ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Object o); but not ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Serializable o)

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream, marker-interfaces

In Java, we use the `writeObject(Object obj)` method of `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize an `Object`.

But since the method only takes object that implements the `java.io.Serializable` interface (or it will throw `NotSerializableException`), why does it still use the `Object` parameter rather than `Serializable`, like `writeObject(Serializable o)`?

Is there any designing consideration?

Comment: The only benefit is that you can sub class ObjectOutputStream with a custom serialization which doesn't have to be Serializable though this breaks the general contract for this class.  I suspect that the reason for this is that some serializable types didn't have this interface e.g. arrays like byte[]. These now implement Serializable but I suspect this was not always the case. Arrays still don't follow OOP design in Java particularly well.